# mysql database populate

Tags: sql, mysql

How should we treat the data if they have no values in it. I mean, at some places, they have no value. Should we populate it as it or should we write something at that place?

Comment: Ummm, are you worried about having NULL values in columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of the [`NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) value is a common source of confusion for newcomers to SQL, who often think that `NULL` is the same as an empty string '', or a value of zero.

This is not the case. Conceptually, `NULL` means "a missing unknown value" and it is treated somewhat differently from other values. For example, to test for `NULL`, you cannot use the arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>`.

If you have columns that may contain "a missing unknown value", you have to set them to accept `NULL`s, and use a `NULL` value as [@codaddict suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905319/mysql-database-populate/3905330#3905330).

Comment: so i just need to place NULL there in the table where there is no value given?right?

Comment: And it is applicable to any data type. Like for strings or INt or both...should I enclosed The "NULL" like this or just simply NULL?

Comment: Yes, it's valid for any data type, except when the column is the primary key... And no, do not wrap it in quotes. Example: `INSERT INTO your_table (id, name, surname) VALUES (1, 'Bob', NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a special value called [`NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) in such cases.

Comment: so i just need to place NULL there in the table where there is no value given?right?

Comment: Yes. You can also give the column `NULL` as the default value. Then not inserting any value for that column will automatically insert a `NULL` there.

Comment: And it is applicable to any data type. Like for strings or INt or both...should I enclosed The "NULL" like this or just simply NULL?

Comment: Yes, it applies to column with any data type.